# Storyboard "show" segue doesn't work (only in one case) after updating to xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, xcode7

I have a simple storyboard show segue with id `temp` and I fire it from the first view controller with this line of code `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("temp", sender: self)`.

I put a breakpoint in the `prepareForSegue` function and everything goes fine, but instead of open the destination view controller it remains on the first one, without reacting to any tap.

I checked the ID, recreated the destination view controller and the segue, but nothing changes.

PS: Everything was fine before updating to xcode7 and iOS9.

Comment: Do you have an `UITextView` in destination view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem on my app. After hours of headache I found the problem was related to an `UITextView` in destination view controller. I don't now why but deleting that `UITextView` and recreating it solved the issue.
I think is something related to conversion and `UITextView` but I cannot say what.

Comment: If I remove it the problem disappears, but when I recreate it the problem returns.. Can you tell me everything you did please?

Comment: Sure: I removed the `UITextView` from destination view controller, re-dragged `UITextView` control from Interface Builder in the view controller and set its auto layouts constraints (and of course re connected events from code)

Comment: It's a mystery but it works! You saved me! Thank you very much!

Comment: I also noticed that in my case I used this symbol `-` as text of the `UITextView` and if I remove the symbol everything goes fine.

Comment: So it may be related to text in the `UITextView` and not to control itself. I had "notes: " as text before removing and re-adding. I will try to place text in the new `UITextView` (now it is empty) from IB and check if problems still appears. Thanks for suggestion.